# How to override Django many to many field add() and remove() methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals, manytomanyfield, django-activity-stream

I am trying to set up a Facebook-like activity notification system using [Django-Activity-Stream](https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The library provides a special `action` signal for creating the actions. According to the documentation, to trigger this `action`,

> You can do it through custom forms or by overriding predefined model methods, such as `Model.save()`. The logic is to simply import the action signal and send it with your actor, verb, target, and any other important arguments. For example, `action.send(request.user, verb='reached level 10')`

However, I have an intermediate through model from which the `action` signal has to be sent. Since `Model.save()` method is not called when M2M `add()` or `remove()` methods are instead used, **I want to know if there is any way to override those `add()` and `remove()` methods**.

I have thought about using M2M changed signals but soon realized that I wouldn't be able to easily access request.user in M2M changed signals. (I need to always know who request.user is to generate any useful activity notifications). I am concerned that accessing a user instance in a signal (by creating a separate middleware to store request.user in a thread, for example) may be costly and unsafe. If it is a reliable option, please tell me.